# Is Bayes risk under MSE (i.e. conditional variance) strictly monotonic?

Tags: regression, variance, information-theory, mse, risk

**Formal question**: Let $Y,X,X'$ be r.v.s . Let $E_{X}[Var(Y|X)]$ denote the expected conditional variance (i.e. Bayes risk when predicting $Y$ using $X$ under squared error) and $f$ be a bijective transformation (it's ok to restrict to continuous) is it true that:

$$ E_{X}[Var(Y|X)] < E_{X'}[Var(Y|X')] \iff E_{X}[Var(f(Y)|X)] < E_{X'}[Var(f(Y)|X')] $$

**Intuition**: if you are good at predicting $Y$ you should be good at predicting $exp(Y)$ or $Y +b$ or $aY$... In other words, suppose I'm predicting / regressing a r.v. $Y$ using either samples from r.v. $X$ or $X'$ as input. Intuitively, if $X$ is a better predictor than $X'$ of $Y$ then it has more "information" about $Y$ and will thus be a better predictor about some new r.v. $f(Y)$ that has the same "information" as $Y$.

Further information:

- in the case of conditional discrete entropy, which is the Bayes risk under the log loss when $Y$ is discrete, this holds because of invariance to objections $H[f(Y)|X] = H[Y|X] $
- in the case of conditional differential entropy, which is the Bayes risk under the log loss when $Y$ is continuous, this also holds because $h[f(Y)|X] = h[Y|X] + E[\log \left\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right\vert ] $
- in the case of linear $f$ this holds because $E_{X}[Var(aY+b)|X)] = a^2 E_{X}[Var(Y|X)]$.
- by Bayes risk under squared error I mean $E_{X}[Var(Y|X)] = \inf_g  E_{Y,X} [ || Y - g(X) ||^2 ]$

This seems so intuitive and yet I'm unable to find any information about it nor able to prove that.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc thanks I changed the second f to g. Yes exactly bijective is definitely needed (maybe even continuity) but I see what you at trying to do, I'll think about it

Comment: Without continuity, maybe something like this $Y|X$ ~ flat in [-1,1] and $Y|X'$ is flat in [-2,-1] and [1,2] and now think of $f$ which maps [-1,0] to [-2,-1] and [0,1] to [1,2] and vica versa. It will be bijective.

Comment: You can do it even with continuity. $Y|X$ ~ uniform [0,1], $Y|X'$ ~ uniform [-2,0] now take $f$ to be Parametric ReLU like function and adjust the parameter until variance is smaller on the left quadrant.

Comment: I see no reason for this preservation of the order to hold in the general case. And no clear motivation for the comparison since the Bayes risks are over different sampling distributions.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc thanks I think you are correct.  I don't think that $Y$  can satisfy the distribution you said for all x and all x' but you can turn it into an example that works for some x and x'. Let $Y$ be uniform in $[-10,10]$ and $X=0$ if $Y \in [0,1]$ or $X=Y$ otherwise, similarly for $X'$ and $[-2,0]$. Then  $Y | X$ is a delta function for $X \not \in [0,1]$ and uniform as you said for $X=0$ similarly for $X'$. The delta functions have 0 variance so do not contribute. You can then apply the pReLU as you said, to decrease the variance at $X=0$ while keeping delta functions for the rest.

Comment: If you make it an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: I still believe that the intuition of what I was trying to get at holds,  no for all $f$ but for most $f$. Formally, let $F$ be a r.v. over bijective functions then something like : $E_{X}[Var(Y|X)] < E_{X'}[Var(Y|X')]$ $\iff$ $E_{f \sim F}[E_{X}[Var(f(Y)|X)]] < E_{f \sim F}[E_{X'}[Var(f(Y)|X')]]$. 

@Xi'an these are over different distributions but highly related as the "'tasks" $Y$ and $f(Y)$ have the same information ($I[Y,f(Y)]=I[Y,Y]=I[(Y),f(Y)]$). For $X$ to be a good predictor of $Y$ it needs high mutual information with $Y$ and will thus have high MI with $f(Y)$. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Xi'an To be clear my intuition mostly uses information theory but variance/entropy (and MSE/log loss) are highly related. For one the Bayes risk under MSE is the Bayes risk under log loss when you can only use Gaussian predictors with fix variance. What's more there are well known upper bounds of entropy using the variance, and in some case lower bounds also so you can sandwich the entropy by some functions of the variance.